# NodeJS - Jest unit test setTimeout in process.on callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to unit test a timer using Jest in my `process.on('SIGTERM')` callback but it never seems to be called. I am using `jest.useFakeTimers()` and while it does seem to mock the `setTimeout` call to an extent, it doesn't end up in the `setTimeout.mock` object when checking it.

My index.js file:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    console.log('Got SIGTERM');

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Timer was run');
    }, 300);
});

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Timer 2 was run');
}, 30000);
```

and the test file:

```
describe('Test process SIGTERM handler', () => {
    test.only('runs timeout', () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers();
        process.exit = jest.fn();

        require('./index.js');

        process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGTERM');

        jest.runAllTimers();

        expect(setTimeout.mock.calls.length).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

and the test fails:

> Expected value to be (using ===):
>         2
>       Received:
>         1
>   and the console log output is:

```
console.log tmp/index.js:10
    Timer 2 was run

  console.log tmp/index.js:2
    Got SIGTERM
```

How do I get the `setTimeout` to be run here?

Comment: Try changing sigterm to sighup for a test. It is possible that sigterm kills the process. Also try to remove timer 1 and check if console log actually worked in a sync way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What can be possible done, is to mock the processes `on` method to make sure your handler will be called on `kill` method.

One way to make sure the handler will be called is to mock `kill` alongside `on`.

```
describe('Test process SIGTERM handler', () => {
    test.only('runs timeout', () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers();

        processEvents = {};

        process.on = jest.fn((signal, cb) => {
          processEvents[signal] = cb;
        });

        process.kill = jest.fn((pid, signal) => {
            processEvents[signal]();
        });

        require('./index.js');

        process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGTERM');

        jest.runAllTimers();

        expect(setTimeout.mock.calls.length).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

Other way, a more general one, is to mock the handler within a `setTimeout` and test that is has been called like following:

**`index.js`**

```
var handlers = require('./handlers');

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    console.log('Got SIGTERM');
    setTimeout(handlers.someFunction, 300);
});
```

**`handlers.js`**

```
module.exports = {
    someFunction: () => {}
};
```

**`index.spec.js`**

```
describe('Test process SIGTERM handler', () => {
    test.only('sets someFunction as a SIGTERM handler', () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers();

        process.on = jest.fn((signal, cb) => {
            if (signal === 'SIGTERM') {
                cb();
            }
        });

        var handlerMock = jest.fn();

        jest.setMock('./handlers', {
            someFunction: handlerMock
        });

        require('./index');

        jest.runAllTimers();

        expect(handlerMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this!